# How can I fill a field with current user in form using CreateView/UpdateView in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've been looking for this for few days and I couldn't solve it, so here is my problem:

I'm trying to create a product using just CreateView in views.py for now (My idea is to create forms and pass everything to a function in views.py), but there is one field that I want it to be auto-filled with the logged user ('owner'). I've tried using the `get_initial` in the createView for now, but it doesn't work.

I want to say that this it actually creates a form in which I have to fill all the fields and it works fine, but I want to auto-fill the 'owner' field with the current user logged in.

For now I tried to use the get_initial as I said before, but seems that it does not work. I also tried lots of things that I've seen here, in stackoverflow, but any of them worked for me.

Here I put all the relevant code, but if you need anything else please, ask for it and I'll upload it.

This is my `views.py`:

```
# view for the product entry page
class ProductCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    fields = ['owner', 'category', 'tag', 'name', 'content_tweet']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(ProductCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        return form

    def get_initial(self):
        return {
             'owner': self.request.user,
        }

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_superuser or request.user.is_vendor:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is the model I'm using in `models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(_('Product Name'), max_length=150)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    content_tweet = models.CharField(_('Content Tweet'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    content_abstract = models.CharField(_('Content Abstract'), max_length=3000, blank=True)
    canvas_1 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/canvas_1/', blank=True)
    price_tweet = models.IntegerField(_('Tweet Price in Tokens'), default=0)
    price_abstract = models.IntegerField(_('Abstract Price in Tokens'), default=50)
    price_canvas_1 = models.IntegerField(_('Canvas 1 Price in Tokens'), default=500)
    it_exist = models.BooleanField(_('is an existing idea?'), default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this product should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting products.'
        ),
    )
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'owner')

    def get_categories(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.category.all()])

    def get_tags(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.tag.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this is the template I'm using (for now) in my `XX.html`:

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <div >
        <span class="text-danger la">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    </div>
    <label  >{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is specifically covered in the documentation: [Models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.owner = self.request.user
    return super(ProductCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

override `form_valid` method of `CreateView` as above

Comment: Thank you very much! that works for me :) 

I've tried to delete the `get_initial` and worked too, could you please tell me where I should use the `get_initial` and where the `form_valid`?

I know it is another question, but I have to ask to know why the first is not necessary here :)

Comment: for now i can refer you a [link](https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelclassbasedviews.html)